# Duda Cursos y Procedure PLSQL Básico

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando con plqsql y tengo problemas con los cursores y necesito un poco de ayuda.

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que compare una variable de un procedure en mi caso "dato" y que si es igual a un dni de la tabla EJERCICIO me muestre el nombre y edad de dicha persona, estoy bastante cerca o eso creo pero no consigo sacarlo ya que me devuelve mas datos de los que yo pido y no me da el nombre y edad, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

MI CÓDIGO:

```
 CREATE TABLE EJERCICIO
 (
 DNI NUMBER(9),
 NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20),
 APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(30),
 EDAD NUMBER(2)
 );

 INSERT INTO EJERCICIO VALUES (123456789, 'Antonio', 'Rodriguez', '42');
 INSERT INTO EJERCICIO VALUES (987654321, 'Fernando', 'Dominguez', '32');
 INSERT INTO EJERCICIO VALUES (159753698, 'Jose', 'Hernandez', '28');
 INSERT INTO EJERCICIO VALUES (152634789, 'Lucia', 'Fernandez', '23');


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CURRANTES (dato NUMBER)
 IS
 CURSOR cursorasao IS
 SELECT DNI FROM EJERCICIO;
 sel_dni NUMBER(9);
 sel_nom VARCHAR2(20);
sel_edad NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
 SELECT NOMBRE INTO sel_nom FROM EJERCICIO;
 SELECT EDAD INTO sel_edad FROM EJERCICIO;
 OPEN cursorasao;
  LOOP
   FETCH cursorasao INTO sel_dni;
   EXIT WHEN cursorasao%NOTFOUND;
   IF sel_dni = dato THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sel_nom);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sel_edad);
   END IF;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE cursorasao;
END;

 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 BEGIN
 CURRANTES(123456789);
 END;
```

---

Este es el error que me da :

```
ORA-01422: la recuperación exacta devuelve un número mayor de filas que el solicitado.
```

Comment: Este es el error que me da :  ORA-01422: la recuperación exacta devuelve un número mayor de filas que el solicitado.

Comment: Los comentarios son para hacer aclaraciones, el error debe ir en tu misma pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

@SqlMaker aquí de pleno vas a tener un excepción,por que la sentencia INTO solo puede asignar un registro a tu variable sel_nom o sel_edad y le estas enviando 4 registros

```
SELECT NOMBRE INTO sel_nom FROM EJERCICIO;
SELECT EDAD INTO sel_edad FROM EJERCICIO;
```

Te recomiendo que captures el nombre y la edad  una vez este abierto el Cursor

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE CURRANTES (dato IN INT, CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )   
IS   
BEGIN   
OPEN CURSOR FOR SELECT NOMBRE, EDAD FROM EJERCICIO WHERE DNI=DATO; 
END;
```

Comment: Deberias de explicar que es lo que hace tu codigo y no solo decir "prueba con esto", esto se considera como una respuesta de baja calidad.